# How to make two WORD to DWORD

Tags: c#

```
        short val1 = short.MaxValue;
        short val2 = short.MaxValue;

        int result = val1;
        result |= val2 << 16;

        Console.WriteLine( "Result =\t" + result );         //2147450879
        Console.WriteLine( "Expected =\t" + int.MaxValue ); //2147483647
```

Comment: Can you explain (1) *why* you expect the incorrect result, and (2) *what* you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to merge two signed word in a dword. And this is a test that i'm not sure enough about the correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like C#. Short is signed. A signed negative value extended to int will fill all the leftmost 16 bits. Thus, the proposed code will fail whenever "val1" is negative.

This code works (note that WORD and DWORD are unsigned quantities):

```
  public static uint MakeDWord(ushort a, ushort b) {
    return ((uint)a << 16) | b;
  }
```

Comment: no it shouldn't, that would overlap the first bit of b with the last of a

Answer (score 8):

`short` is signed, so the maximum value is `0x7FFF`. Concatenated this results in `0x7fff7fff` instead of `0x7fffffff` which is 2147450879. So what you're seeing is actually correct.

Comment: Argh, yes. Sorry. Need ... more ... tea.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
        ushort val1 = ushort.MaxValue;
        ushort val2 = ushort.MaxValue;

        int result = val1;
        result |= val2 << 15;
```

Comment: That answer is still wrong. The reason is that you're merging bit 15 of val1 with bit 0 of val2.
In general, you want to stay unsigned when you do bit shifting and arithmetic. Signed values are mostly good for regular arithmetic, although you get away with shift operators as long as you know the domain of the numbers is positive or zero. But if you know that -- why not make it unsigned?

Comment: well you do for this special case.
In general however you would want to << 16 so that val2 falls into the higher half of the result. Furthermore you if your result is a signed int it might make more sense for val2 to be signed too so you would get int.MaxValue instead of -1

Answer (score 1):

try this, similar to MAKEWORD in < windef.h >:

```
#define MAKEDWORD(_a, _b)   ((DWORD)(((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(_a)) & 0xffff)) | ((DWORD)((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(_b)) & 0xffff))) << 16))
```